# How should I structure data in MySQL for a one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, join

I am designing a system in which a file can have a variable number of custom sub fields. I need to be able to retrieve and filter files with all the attached fields. The fields are customizable in name and number by the user. What is the best practice for this situation?

I am thinking of setting it up to have the following structure

```
TABLE files

id  file_name
1   My file
2   My other file

TABLE file_fields

id | file_id | field_id | value
1   1          1          microwave
2   1          2          a machine that heats stuff up
3   1          3          43.54
4   2          1          oven
5   2          3          34.22


fields TABLE

id  |  title
1      Name of product
2      Description of product
3      Price of product
```

I could then run a query that joins and concats file_fields records and joins them to file records... but is that clumsy? Is there a way to json_encode those fields efficiently instead of concat values separated by pipes? A query that would return something like.

```
id -> 1
file_name -> My file
fields -> 1|Name of product|microwave|2|Description of product|a machine that heats stuff up|3|Price of product|43.54

id -> 2
file_name -> My other file
fields -> 1|Name of product|oven|3|Price of product|34.22
```

Would there be any serious disadvantages of just encoding all the field data as JSON and storing in a text field? For searching, you could just do carefully formatted text-searches...

I am leaning toward doing something like this

```
TABLE files

id  file_name      field_values_json
1   My file        {"1":"microwave","2":"a machine that heats stuff up","3":"43.54"}
2   My other file   {"1":"oven","3":"34.22"}

TABLE fields

id  |  title
1      Name of product
2      Description of product
3      Price of product
```

Any thoughts on this approach?

Comment: I believe this pattern is called "entity attribute value", just in case you didn't know that, using that terminology should help you with searching for more info on it.

Comment: Implementing an efficient EAV model is an order of magnitude more complicated than the standard relational model. EAV can get us an incredible amount of flexibility with no database schema changes, but it also introduces quite a bit of complexity, just to emulate a `SELECT * FROM` query.

Comment: When obliged to consider an EAV model, I like to spit the attributes out into separate tables according to data type

Comment: @Don'tPanic Updated my question with an idea... what do you think?

Comment: do you use any language to pull data from DB?

Comment: The application is written in PHP, so I can decode everything after its returned.